# Custom news letter

Tags: emails, notifications

Drupal Version: 6.26.

I need a news letter, which I can send to users of certain group informing them about an activity, which they are supposed to do today or in future. (This activity will be set by admin)

Until that activity is not done, the user should be informed on daily basis.

There exits modules for newsletters (like **Simplenews**), but I am not able to find a way to reference a particular newsletter to trigger on some interval by checking pending activity.

If anybody got interested to know more, then I am here to answer you.

Your help would be very helpful.

Comment: Not sure if it will fit you, but you can use the `Rules` and `Rules scheduler`modules to do this.

Comment: No it doesn't fit...